# What is the recommended style of the "message" in a JUnit test?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit3

What is the recommended style of the "message" in a JUnit test?

Here is the message expressed currently:

```
ReturnedObject ro = objectUnderTest.methodToTest(stub);
Assert.assertNotNull("The object was null!", ro);
```

Or, is this more correct?

```
ReturnedObject ro = objectUnderTest.methodToTest(stub);
Assert.assertNotNull("Verify that the object was not null.", ro);
```

Please pay attention, as you answer my question, to the appearance of the message from the point of view of the user.

Comment: IMO neither; rather include actual useful information.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to read exactly what failed directly from the failure message. Which conveys the most useful information?

1. `java.lang.AssertionError: The object was null!`
2. `java.lang.AssertionError: Verify that the object was not null.`
3. `java.lang.AssertionError: ObjectUnderTest.methodToTest returned null.`

*Beyond that, it's just a matter of team style.*